# chmod 755 all Mach-O executables - macosx

Tags: macos, shell, chmod

I'm trying to arrive at a shell command where I need to modify permission to 755 for files which have "Mach-O executable" as file command output.

I was able to arrive at this - `find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep executable`

But how do I chmod 755 on them?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -exec file {} + |
sed -n -e '/Mach-O .* executable/s/:.*//p' |
xargs chmod 755
```

By using `+` instead of `\;`, the `file` command will be executed less often (it acts a bit like `xargs` does).  The `sed` command doesn't print by default (`-n`), but looks for Mach-O executables and removes the material after the `:` after the file name, so it lists the files.  And the `xargs` command runs `chmod 755` on the arguments it reads from standard input.  Assuming you don't have executable file names containing newlines, blanks, tabs and other oddball characters, that should do the job.  If you don't stick to the POSIX portable file name character set, you may have to work harder.

Note that if there are no executables under the current directory, then you'll get a usage message from `chmod` because `xargs` runs the command once even if there are no arguments.  GNU `xargs` has an option `-r` to avoid that 'run on empty' invocation of the command; the version on macOS does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `gawk`+ `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -print0 -exec file {} \; | gawk -F\: '/Mach-O .* executable/ {print $1}' |xargs chmod 755
```